# Why does $\sin(\operatorname e^i)$ in complex variables have the following solution?

Tags: complex-analysis

If possible I would like to know the definitions to look at so I can master this material.
According to my professor 
$$
\sin(\operatorname e^i) = \sin(\cos1)\cosh(\sin1)+i\cos(\cos1)\sinh(\sin1)
$$

I al wondering how this works exactly for a better understanding at what's on hand.

Comment: $e^i = \cos 1 + i \sin 1$. Now use the addition theorem, and $\cos (ix) = \cosh x,\; \sin (ix) = i \sinh x$.

Comment: I tend to over think things and I realized you just apply the definition for e to the iz. I wish that I could stop over thinking things.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*} \sin e^i &= \sin (\cos 1 + i \sin 1) \\ &= \sin(\cos 1) \cos(i \sin 1) + \cos(\cos 1) \sin (i \sin 1) \\ &= \sin(\cos 1) \cosh(\sin 1) + i \cos(\cos 1) \sinh(\sin 1), \end{align*}$$ where we used $$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin \theta,$$ the angle addition identity $$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta,$$ and the hyperbolic identities $$\cosh iz = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} = \cos z,$$ $$\sinh iz = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2} = i \sin z.$$